# How to pass a text while firing an event? 

Tags: c#

I need to pass a checkeditem of a checklistbox while firing an event from a dynamic checklistbox. The code snippet is provided below with comments...
I'm facing an issue with the same piece of code. On mouse double click event its throwing an exception saying IndexoutofRange. Its working fine with the index value 0.Please help 2 solve me both.

```
private void clbTables_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    int indexofselectedtable;
    indexofselectedtable = Convert.ToInt32(clbTables.SelectedIndex); 
    if (clbTables.CheckedItems.Count != 0)
    {
        Metadata metadataobj = new Metadata(dbProperties);
        DBList = metadataobj.GetColumns(clbTables.CheckedItems[indexofselectedtable].ToString()); // This throws an error on checking an item of index>0.

        for (int j = 0; j < DBList.Count; j++)
        {
            chklistcolumns.Name = "chklist" + j++;
            chklistcolumns.Items.Add(DBList.ElementAt(j));
        }
        this.Controls.Add(chklistcolumns);

        chklistcolumns.ItemCheck += new ItemCheckEventHandler(OnCheckListBoxItemCheck);
    }
}

private void OnCheckListBoxItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs args) //need to pass the tablename which can be got from the object clbTables
{   
    Columns columnobj = new Columns();
    columnobj.ColumnName = this.Text;
    columnobj.Id = this.Name;
    columnobj.TableName= // need to get the tablename from the object clbtables
}
```

Comment: clbTables.CheckedItems - what is the type of object returned by this property. Is it possible to check multiple items in the checkedlistbox ? If not, the list would always be of length 1 - i.e. index 0 would the only valid lookup. You don't need to key in by SelectedIndex perhaps....

Comment: clbTables.CheckedItems returns a List. Sometimes i'm able to check more than 1 element. I even selected 6 items using the same code. But throws the Indexoutofbound exception in between.

Answer (score 0):

I think I see what the issue here is, you are trying to match the selected index of your CheckedListBox with an index in the CheckedItems collection, but it doesn't work that way.

Consider this: you have 10 items in your CheckedListBox, and three of them are checked.  That gives you .Items[10] and .CheckedItems[3]. If then you double click on the 7th item in the CheckedListBox, your SelectedIndex will be 6, but there will only be three items in the CheckedItems collection. So when you try to read clbTables.CheckedItems[6] you are going to be outside of the range of that collection.

Answer (score 0):

`clbTables.CheckedItems` is another collection. You can't use `clbTables.SelectedIndex` in it.

Why not just to use `SelectedValue` property?

Comment: I'm just adding the items to the checklistbox and as a result i dont have a value assigned to it. Hence my selectedvalue is always null. How can i do that along with this code?  
clbTables.Items.Add(TableList.ElementAt(i));